# find the index of max value in data frame and add the value

Tags: r

This is my data frame:

```
>head(dat)
  geno    P1    P2    P3    P4   dif
1   G1 0.015 0.007 0.026 0.951 0.001
2   G2 0.008 0.006 0.015 0.970 0.001
3   G3 0.009 0.006 0.017 0.968 0.000
4   G4 0.011 0.007 0.017 0.965 0.000
5   G5 0.013 0.005 0.021 0.961 0.000
6   G6 0.009 0.006 0.007 0.977 0.001
```

Here, I need to find max in each row and add dat$dif to the max. 
when i used `which.max(dat[,-1])`, I am getting error:

```
Error in which.max(dat[,-1]) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: You can get the row max using `apply(df[-1] , 1 , max)` - where the `1` indicates the max is taken across the rows. The df[-1] removes the first non-numeric column from the apply function. You can then sum this to dif : `df$tot <- df$dif + apply(df[-1] , 1 , max)`

Comment: Can you try `as.numeric(dat[,-1])` in place of `dat[,-1]`?

Comment: It might never matter on your data, but you don't want the last column considered in the max either, right?

Answer (score 1):

A previous answer (by Scriven) gives most of it but as others have stated, it incorrectly includes the last column. Here is one method that works around it:

```
idx <- (! names(dat) %in% c('geno','dif'))
dat$dif + apply(dat[,idx], 1, max)
#     1     2     3     4     5     6 
# 0.952 0.971 0.968 0.965 0.961 0.978
```

You can easily put the `idx` stuff directly into the `dat[,...]` subsetting, but I broke it out here for clarity.

`idx` can be defined by numerous things here, such as "*all but the first and last columns*": `idx <- names(dat)[-c(1, ncol(dat))]`; or "*anything that looks like P#*": `idx <- grep('^P[0-9]+', names(dat))`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Here, I am aware that the last column will not be maximum. So i included the last column. Here, I don't want to create a new column, instead i want to replace the max by adding dif. I succeed by using for loop. Is it possible to do the same using apply?

Comment: One problem you'll run into is that, during apply, it will convert everything to the "lowest" data structure; in this case, that's a string, not what you need in order to use `which.max`. A `for` loop will work just fine, and though I'm guilty of over-attempting the `*apply` family of functions, in all honesty if the `for` loop works for you, why spend more time on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's an app, eh function for that :-).

`max.col` finds the index of the maximum position for each row of a matrix. Take note, that as *max.col* expects a matrix (numeric values only) you have to exclude the “geno” column when applying this function.

```
sapply(1:6,function(x) dat[x,max.col(dat[,2:5])[x] +1]) + dat$dif
[1] 0.952 0.971 0.968 0.965 0.961 0.978
```